# update to Android studio 4.1.1

Tags: android-studio, updates

[**This is shown when trying to update, are my previous projects made in Kotlin compatible with the new version of Android? how to solve this problem? **](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gpSre.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Ewfr.png)

Answer (score 0):

First, go to File >> Settings >> Plugins >> Update Kotlin and Firebase Services if updates are available or disable the plugins and install the update then re-enable the plugins again.